# Ubuntu 15.04 disconnects from virtual networks after wakeup

Tags: networking, virtualbox, suspend, vmware, systemd

After upgrade to Ubuntu 15.04, I see the same behavior with VirtualBox and VMWare Workstation. After the system is waked up from suspend, there's neither `vboxnet0` nor `vmnet8` devices in the output of `ifconfig`. In the network menu, both virtual devices are marked as not managed.

In order to start the VMWare Workstation network, I have to `sudo service vmware restart`. Then I see: **"Connection Established. You are now connected to vmnet8"**.

In order to start the VirtualBox network, I go to `File -> Preferences -> Network -> Host-Only Networks -> vboxnet0`.
Then press OK. I see **"Connection Established. You are now connected to vboxnet0"**.

The question is, how to make virtual networks start automatically? It looks like a systemd issue since I haven't seen anything like that previously.

Comment: FWIW there's a VirtualBox issue here: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/13873

Comment: I have the same problem as well.  I could not find a solution anywhere, and it seems the VirtualBox ticket is not been dealt with.  Have you found a solution, by any chance?

Comment: No, I'm still suffering from this.

Comment: The same here with Ubuntu 15.04 64 bit and Virtualbox 4.3.26_Ubuntur98988

Answer (score 2):

### Making it work manually

I have solved this problem typing the following command in a terminal after wake up:

```
sudo ifconfig vboxnet0 192.168.50.1/24
```

I'm not really sure if 192.168.50.1 is the VirtualBox default IP, but it's the one that my Virtualbox is using, if yours is using another you have to replace the IP.

### Making it work automatically

To make it work automatically while the system wakes up I have created a file in the folder:

```
/lib/systemd/system-sleep/
```

The content of that file should be something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
ifconfig vboxnet0 192.168.50.1/24
```

Make the file executable with:

```
chmod a+x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/name_of_file.sh
```

Since it's a root file, you'd need to be sudo to create the file, but we don't need to include the sudo in the script.

Hope it's helpful!

*NOTE: Just tested on Ubuntu 15.10*

Answer (score 0):

jjcarrion's answer fixes the network after waking up from sleep, but you can also keep sleep from interfering with the network in the first place, by adding:

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=interface-name:vboxnet0
```

to `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`.  Tested on 15.10.

Answer (score 0):

(Fast way) It is not good but it works.

Go to `Virtual Machine Settings > Hardware`

And **Remove Network Adapter**

Then **Add new one** (Use NAT)